# Using react-native-background-timer

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a simple android app. I'm trying to get my phone to vibrate every 3 seconds for now. This is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => {
        Vibration.vibrate(1000);
    }, 3000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackgroundTimer.stopBackgroundTimer();
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView>
                {this.state.errors.map(e => {
                    const {error, solved, errorInfo, key, uid, date} = e;
                    return (
                        <View key={e.key} style={{backgroundColor: solved === true ? 'green' : '#ff5b68'}}>
                            <Text>{error}</Text>
                            <Text>{errorInfo}</Text>
                            <Text>{key}</Text>
                            <Text>{uid}</Text>
                            <Text>{date}</Text>
                            <MarkedAsSolvedButton id={key} solved={solved}/>
                        </View>
                    )
                })}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNBackgroundTimer.start')

What am I missing?

I'm using this module: https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer

Comment: did you run react-native link ?

Comment: if you are testing it on ios then do check the pods!

Comment: I did link it. I am testing it on Android

Comment: then check build.gradle and see that if the implemention and project link are included or not? in you native andorid code please

Comment: I have never worked with Android development before. What am I looking for?

Comment: it is not possible with if you are using expo,because linking you can not do

Answer (score 1):

You can use clearInterval method. First declare a global variable to easily start and end timer.The sample code is given below:

```
let myTimer;
class ABC extends React.Component {
componentDidMount()
{
myTimer = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(()=> {
// Your repeated task here.
}, 3000);
}
componentWillUnMount()
{
  // Code to stop timer.
 BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(myTimer);
}
render() {
// remaining code
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the component need to be started first before using it. make a call to BackgroundTimer.start() first and then try your logic.

Comment: Where do you think I should add it?

Comment: On componentDidMount() method

Comment: Are you using create-react-native-app? If so, as per documentation, eject it before running react-native link.

Comment: I'm using expo. I did eject it before

Comment: The problem must be there at linking the package. Make sure the package is linked properly at MainApplication and settings.gradle. This link may be useful for you https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer/issues/35